# problema renderizando objetos | canvas tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, interfaz-gráfica

estoy intentando hacer un programa sensillo en tkinter en el que el personaje pueda "caminar" por un bosque. Este es el código:

```py
from tkinter import *; import random

root = Tk()

root.geometry(f"{root.winfo_screenwidth()}x{root.winfo_screenheight()}")    

canvas = Canvas(root, bg="#052b05")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

loading=canvas.create_text(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2,
root.winfo_screenheight()/2, text="loading, please wait...", 
font=("calibri bold", 30), fill="white")

root.update()


x, y, xvel, yvel= 0,0,0,0

trees, basetreex, basetreey=[], [], []

for i in range(random.randint(5, 5)):   # original: 50-150

    treex=random.randint(-2000,2000)     # original: -5000, 5000
    treey=random.randint(-2000,2000)     # original: -5000, 5000
    treemodel=random.choice(["arbol1 krita.png", "arbol2 krita.png", "arbol3 krita.png"])

    basetreex.append(treex); basetreey.append(treey)


    Image=PhotoImage(file=treemodel)

    Tree=canvas.create_image(treex+x, treey+y, image=Image)
    trees.append(Tree)


canvas.create_oval(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2+20,root.winfo_screenheight()/2+20,
root.winfo_screenwidth()/2-20,root.winfo_screenheight()/2-20, fill="black")

canvas.delete(loading)

KeysPressed=[]

def NewKey(event):

    global KeysPressed

    if event.char not in KeysPressed:

        KeysPressed.append(event.char)




def DelKey(event):

    global KeysPressed

    KeysPressed.pop(KeysPressed.index(event.char))


root.bind("<KeyPress>", NewKey) # key detection

root.bind("<KeyRelease>", DelKey)


while True:

    #canvas.delete("all")




    counter = 0

    for tree in trees:  


        treeCoords = canvas.coords(tree)



        treex, treey = treeCoords[0], treeCoords[1]


        #if 1600 > treex + x > -200 and 1200 > treey + y > -200:


        canvas.move(tree, treex-treex * 2, treey-treey * 2) # llevar el objeto a x0 y0      
        canvas.move(tree, x+basetreex[counter], y+basetreey[counter]) # cambiar x por x+basex 

        #print(basetreex[counter], basetreey[counter])


        counter += 1

        #print(x, y)


        #try:

            #print("coordenadas base x: ", basetreex[counter],"coordenadas base y: ", y+basetreey[counter], "contador: ", counter, 

            #"\n \n coordenadas en el canvas: ", canvas.coords(tree), "coordenadas del mundo: ", x, y)

        #except:
        #   pass



    if "w" in KeysPressed:

        yvel += 1

    if "s" in KeysPressed:

        yvel -= 1

    if "d" in KeysPressed:

        xvel -= 1

    if "a" in KeysPressed:

        xvel += 1

    x += xvel
    y += yvel

    xvel /= 1.02 # fricción
    yvel /= 1.02


    root.update()
```

mi problema es que en vez de que los árboles aparezcan en lugares aleatorios, siempre aparecen en las coordenadas -2000, -2000, pero cuando imprimo las coordenadas de cada objeto, son todas distintas. También probé a imprimir la variable counter, y funciona bien, así que supongo que estoy usando mal el canvas.move, pero no tengo idea. Hay alguna forma de arreglar el código? Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el recolector de basura está eliminando el resto de tus imágenes (por lo que solo creas el objeto `Imagen = PhotoImage(file=treemodel)` y luego lo sobreescribes, solo se queda con el último `PhotoImage` cargado)

La solución es guardarlo en una lista, para que no sean eliminadas (lo llamé `imgmaster`)

```
imgmaster = []
for i in range(random.randint(5, 5)):   # original: 50-150
    treex=random.randint(-2000,2000)     # original: -5000, 5000
    treey=random.randint(-2000,2000)     # original: -5000, 5000
    treemodel=random.choice(["arbol1 krita.png", "arbol2 krita.png", "arbol3 krita.png"])
    basetreex.append(treex); basetreey.append(treey)
    imgmaster.append(PhotoImage(file=treemodel))
    Tree=canvas.create_image(treex+x, treey+y, image=imgmaster[i])
    trees.append(Tree)
```